# How to resolve a jQuery Cycle stylesheet console error

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, wordpress

To intro myself, I am an absolute noob when it comes to jQuery/Javascript and the implementation of my code was done via altering publically available snippets and hours of sifting through instructional content, so please excuse my idiocy if I get terminology/code or anything of the like incorrect.

I created a bunch of jQuery Cycle image sliders on a website that seemed to work perfectly fine. The loading time of this specific page, however, was quite long, and upon inspection using dev tools, I came across some basic errors that I was able to fix.

The problem is that I'm stuck on the last error I need to solve and have tried a few things to troubleshoot but with my limited knowledge I am sure I am simply making a stupid mistake due to not understanding core principles.

Please note that I am ommiting the TLD in the code example for privacy reasons but if needed I can provide the actual URL.

Please see my code below:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Example 1</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../jq.css" />
<style type="text/css">
img { border: none }
p { text-align:center }

/* make sure each slide image is centered */
#slideshow2 div img { margin: auto; display: block;}
  
#slideshow2 div { background-color: transparent !important;}

</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    
    $('#slideshow2').cycle({ 
        fx: 'none',
        speed: 1,
        timeout: 700
    }).cycle("pause");
    
    // Pause & play on hover
 $('#slideshow-block2').hover(function(){
  $(this).find('#slideshow2').addClass('active').cycle('resume');
  
 }, function(){
  $(this).find('#slideshow2').removeClass('active').cycle('pause').cycle(0);
 });
    
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
        <div id="slideshow-block2">
            <div id="slideshow2">
                <!-- wrap each image in a div -->
                <div><img src="https://example.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/PH_Guellor-01.webp"/></div>
                <div><img src="https://example.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/example1.webp"/></div>
                <div><img src="https://example.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/example2.webp"/></div>
                <div><img src="https://example.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/example3.webp"/></div>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The above code does not work however and my modules are displaying all janky (Divs overlap and content disappears behind other content etc).
When changing the `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../jq.css" />` to something like `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="jq.css" />` or even trying to link any other stylesheet (I'm actually not even sure where this should link to which might be the core problem), the layout is fixed and appears correctly, but I receive the following console error:
"Refused to apply style from 'https://phlogiston.co.za/our-team/jq.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled."

I have read that this error can be present when the ref attribute does not point to a correct/existing stylesheet.
With this info, I created the jq.css file. On doing so the error disappears, but my layout goes janky again.

If anyone out there can tap me on the fingers and tell me where I am going wrong (if not multiple things) please help point me in the right direction.
I am busy upskilling myself on this, but as they say "Rome was not built in a day".

Any help would be massively appreciated :)

Comment: if your layout is ok, then it definitely should be `href="jq.css"`. As per the error "Refused to apply style from...", last time it happened to me, in my CSS file there was an `import` statement, trying to import another css file which was non-existing. Removed the faulty import, and the error was gone.

Comment: Thanks @GrafiCode for the reply :)
I also think this. The problem is that I'm not sure which style sheet to call here?
When calling my main theme stylesheet I also receive an error. 
Baffled, but I KNOW te solution is something stupid XD